# Why can’t I bind a function () to the onload event and the resize event the same way?

Tags: javascript

Why can’t I bind a function () to the onload event and the resize event the same way?

I want to bind my own functions to javascript’s onresize and onload events.

This is test code in a .JS file.
I made it work by using two different ways to bind my functions to the events.
And it works well.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  alert (“Hi from resize”);
}

window.onload = function () {
  alert (“Hi from onload”);
}
```

However, when I try to use the same way to bind them, one always fails.  I.e. Neither of these work:

```
window.resize = function () {
  alert (“Hi from resize”);
}

window.addEventListener('onload', function() {
  alert (“Hi from onload”);
}
```

I’ve found endless posts on how to make specific examples work one way or the other.

But I can’t find anything that hints at why the same way won’t work  for both.

Can anyone help me figure this out:

--- Someone wrote that addEventListener () is the preferred. And that direct assignment was not.  Is that true?

--- Should direct assignment still work for both events?

--- Should addEventListener () work for both?

--- Am I missing something else that I should know?

I mean the code I have works fine.  It’s just inconsistent, and that always seems to indicate I’ve screwed up somewhere.

And I guess if either way is "Supposed To" work for both events I can go back and search for typos.  But it would help to know which way is preferred, if either.  Or I'm missing something important.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it backwards in your second block. When you're assigning to the window property, the name is `on<eventname>`; when you're using `addEventListener()` you just use `<eventname>`. So it should be:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    alert("Hi from resize");
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    alert("Hi from resize");
});
```

`addEventListener` is preferred these days for a few reasons:

1. You can have multiple listeners, which all execute when the event occurs. When you assign to a property, it replaces the previous value. If you want to remove an event listener, you can use `removeEventListener` selectively (this requires binding to a named function, because you need to pass the same function when removing).
2. It can be used with custom events defined by the application; `onXXX` properties can only be used with standard events.

Comment: Also, you can use window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    alert("Hi from load");
} instead of onload

Comment: You missed a closing parenthesis at the end of your code :)

Comment: To add to my embarassment, I also just found out that I had an "artifact" of prior tries left behind in my HTML page:  <body onload="myFunction ()">.  But none the less the different naming was the key.  Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` is preferred because if you assign you will override any other event that has been assigned to that event.

the event for onload when using `addEventListener` is just "load"